# Typescript: Why does it works?

Tags: typescript

It looks like when we using destruction and dynamic keys typescript works wrong.

Here is the pice of code:

```js
interface ISimple {
  field1: { value: string }
}

let o: ISimple;

const update = (key: string, value: string) => {
  o = { ...o, [key]: value }; // should throw error
}
```

As we see the value of shouldn't be `string` type (should be `{ value: string }`), but typescript doesn't throw an error?

typescript version: 3.7.3

Comment: I am surprised this type checks at all ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That's because.... it doesn't :D

Comment: Excess property checking on object spread is weird in TypeScript.   I don't know exactly why this is happening but possibly related issues in GitHub: [microsoft/TypeScript#32236](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32236) (hi @TitianCernicova-Dragomir), [microsoft/TypeScript#30129](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30129), [microsoft/TypeScript#19775](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19775), [microsoft/TypeScript#27355](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27355)... 

Comment: @jcalz It's not just me, right ? This seems off .. even by spread is strange in TS standards ..